# allow signin but not signup using Google Sign-In

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using Google Sign-In for user authentication. Currently, anyone can log in but I'd like to manually add the users to the firebase authentication and only allow those users to sign in using Google Sign-in.

I can check if the currently signed-in user is new or existing by checking `additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`

```js
    const creds = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    if (creds.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser) {
       await auth().signOut();
       await auth().currentUser?.delete();
    }
```

but by the time I get that information, `onAuthStateChanged` executes and redirects the user to the protected route.

Answer (score 2):

It's counterintuitive to what we know as user flow but it is actually better to allow users to sign up and set conditions that will allow them to use your app. I wouldn't use isNewUser since it only fires once and an app refresh makes this defunct.

I suggest looking at custom claims, for example: allow users to access the page and content if the user has a 'isMember' set to `true` on their profile.

Custom claims can be read by the client and rules freely, and can only be edited through the admin-sdk. so an admin can setup a function to execute a command that updates the user, you could also do this with a node app with the admin-sdk installed.

you can read about [Custom claims here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)